# Is a comparison or if statement faster

Tags: python, performance, if-statement, optimization, comparison

Would doing the following be faster or slower than just an if statement?

```py
mult = x or y 
# Assuming python considers something 
# being "0" as false and something being 1 or higher 
# (or -1 and lower) as true

mult = (x/x) or (y/y) 
# This is in the case Python doesn't do what was
# described above

draw(x, y, 0, 255, 0, 255*mult)
# draw(x_pos, y_pos, red, green, blue, alpha)
```

Not sure how to word this better, let alone if wording it better is necessary. Just something I am curious about as I was talking about optimizing code for performance, and such an idea had come to me but wasn't sure about since Google wasn't providing any helpful results (all were unrelated).

I probably could test this in my own time too, but I feel as if asking someone who would know how computers would work with comparisons vs if statements could be the most helpful.

Comment: [Show us](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) the [benchmark](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) results you've obtained so far.

Comment: I'm still yet to run a benchmark as I am not sure what operations would be the equivalent to running `draw()`, however I'll go ahead and set one up real quick and see what I get.

Comment: What is the "if statement" you are refering to?

Comment: What I am referring to is something along the lines of the following

if x != 0 and y != 0:
    draw(x, y, 0, 255, 0, 255)

Comment: Can you post the if statements to compare? I don't see how 1 and 2 relate. `x/x` is 1 (assuming integer) and so its just an expensive way of writing `1`.

Comment: @tdelaney Reason why I did `x/x` was to reach `1`, or in other words, `True`. Otherwise, if x is 0 `0/0` then it will reach `0`, and in other words, `False`.

Comment: @HatsuneMiku - 0 will be a zero divide exception - slower!

Comment: @tdelaney yup, just discovered that, but otherwise seems to be fine with the other method. In fact, on average, the comparative benchmark ran 37% faster compared to the if statement bench. This was with 1_000_000 operations. As for the comparative average, it was 70ms and the if statement average was 96ms.

Comment: @J_H Sorry for the late response, but I did a benchmark in Python. Would appear they are roughly the same speed, with the if method sometimes being a bit faster. https://stackoverflow.com/a/76965543/16776361

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python converts its operators into method calls. It doesn't know what any of them actually do. The exact rules can get complicated, but more or less, `mult = x or y` turns into

```
mult = x.__bool__() or y.__bool__()
```

`x` and `y` decide what `bool` means to them and return `True` or `False` accordingly. For integers, `0` is `False`, everything else is `True`. `or` short-circuits so if `x` is `True`, the `y` method call is not made.

`mult = (x/x) or (y/y)` turns into something like

```
mult = x.__div__(x).__bool__() or y.__div__(y).__bool__()
```

`x/x` will almost aways be `1` (at least for integers) but python doesn't know that. It needs to make the extra `div` call. That makes it slower. It would be faster to write this as `mult = 1 or 1`, or even better, `mult = 1`. The exception is when a value is `0` as you would get a `ZeroDivisionError`.

`draw(x, y, 0, 255, 0, 255*mult)` vs `draw(x_pos, y_pos, red, green, blue, alpha)`

The first uses literals which are a bit faster than looking up and reading the variables `red`, etc... But it has the cost of the multiplication. 1 will be trivially faster.

None of these different ways of doing things will make a real difference to the execution of the code IMHO. Its all a bit of white noise.

Comment: I see, thanks for answering. Decided to do a quick benchmark in Python, and it does appear as if using comparisons is around 137% as fast as if statements on average. Assuming I did my math correctly atleast. `(63+78+68)/3 = 70` for the comparative bench, then `(90+100+97)/3 = 96` for the if statement bench. Then I did `96/70`, so there's my math if you wish to review it and correct it if there is any mistakes. These results appeared when using 1_000_000 executions, and all numbers are in ms (except for the percentage, of course).

Comment: I'm not sure what your `if` statement looks like, but maybe `mult = x if x else y`. It involves an extra lookup of `x` so a bit slower. The lookup is faster in a function than at module level as function local variables are optimized. I think that the current python optimization effort is going to close some of these gaps. Its all a trivial difference - but I have to admit to using the non-if semantics in my code, readability be damned.

Comment: My if statement looked like, `if x/x == 1 or y/y == 1:`, which I just now realized that shouldn't be and changed it to `if x or y:` and it now appears to be the same speed. Didn't notice this critical error now until I went to go check that if statement as I was supposed to change it to `if x or y:` but forgot to do so. x) However though, looking at current tests, the if statement actually appears to be faster. I am not sure if this is a Python issue, or an issue at machine level.

Answer (score -2):

After running some benchmarks (and resolving some errors). It would appear as if an if-statement is faster than a comparative branchless source method. Here is the GitHub if anyone is interested and wants to check for any errors or mistakes.

https://github.com/Weebed-Coder/comparative_bench

I quickly threw the code together, so there *may* be some mistakes. But, from what I've seen, the if-statement ran a bit faster. Would encourage people to test this too in C/Rust/Assembly to ensure it is as little as a Python related issue as possible.